# I am trying to implement the new paypal return shipping on us asset code

Tags: javascript, paypal

I am trying to use the new Paypal asset code (https://www.paypal.com/uk/webapps/mpp/refunded-returns/business), but it doesn't seem to work. It seems straight forward. I have just pasted the following into a page

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var mpt = new Date(); 
var mpts = mpt.getTimezoneOffset() + mpt.getTime(); 
document.write("<script type=\"text\/javascript\" src=\"https:\/\/altfarm.mediaplex.com\/ad\/js\/\?sz=120x600&lc=en_GB&enc_id=&mpt=" + mpts + "&mpvc=\"><\/script>"); 
</script> 
<noscript> <a href="https://adfarm.mediaplex.com/ad/nc/?sz=120x600&lc=en_GB&enc_id="><img src="https://adfarm.mediaplex.com/ad/nb/?sz=120x600&lc=en_GB&enc_id=" alt="Click Here" border="0"></a> </noscript>
```

But, it produces no result. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I see there is a parameter missing, try using the following ensuring that the size variable reflects the banner size you want:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var mpt = new Date();
var mpts = mpt.getTimezoneOffset() + mpt.getTime();
document.write("<script type=\"text\/javascript\" src=\"http:\/\/altfarm.mediaplex.com\/ad\/js\/27739-224464-12439-0\?enc_id=&sz=120x600&mpt=" + mpts + "&mpvc=\"><\/script>");
</script>
<noscript>
<a target="_blank" href="http://adfarm.mediaplex.com/ad/nc/27739-224464-12439-0?enc_id=BXFC2QNHPNKAG&sz=120x600">
<img src="http://adfarm.mediaplex.com/ad/nb/27739-224464-12439-0?enc_id=&sz=120x600" alt="Click Here" border="0">
</a>
</noscript>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer. And yes it works! Can't understand why the paypal website would be giving out a snippet that doesn't work. I also want to use the following, which also doesn't work

Comment: <script type="text/javascript"> var mpt = new Date(); var mpts = mpt.getTimezoneOffset() + mpt.getTime(); document.write("<script type=\"text\/javascript\" src=\"https:\/\/altfarm.mediaplex.com\/ad\/js\/27739-221689-12439-171\?sz=468x60&lc=en_GB&enc_id=RVZC6UXTBM73Y&mpt=" + mpts + "&mpvc=\"><\/script>"); </script> <noscript> <a href="https://adfarm.mediaplex.com/ad/nc/27739-221689-12439-171?sz=468x60&lc=en_GB&enc_id=RVZC6UXTBM73Y"><img src="https://adfarm.mediaplex.com/ad/nb/27739-221689-12439-171?sz=468x60&lc=en_GB&enc_id=RVZC6UXTBM73Y" alt="Click Here" border="0"></a> </noscript>    Cheers